# Regex - 16 characters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to check a string for 16 characters, however I don't want the regex to consider a string that contains 16 digits.
This is the regex I am using `\w{16}` but the following two examples matches the regex:

```
2107260040003208
MDA0ODcyfEFBQ3w3
```

I want the regex to only match anything like `MDA0ODcyfEFBQ3w3` but if the string is 16 digits, I want to ignore it.

appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Is this regex used to evaluate single strings, or to search inside a larger text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching digits only using a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!\d+$)\w{16}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j1uYlJ/1)

Without the anchors, you can use a word boundary

```
\b(?!\d+\b)\w{16}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR6ZAR/1)

Comment: This won't work for search matches in a larger text though.

Comment: @Nyerguds I have added a version using word boundaries.